# Display Email Headers within Email with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, email, networking, network-programming, email-headers

How would I display the headers of an email within the email itself using JavaScript?

For example:  I know on a webpage I can return HTTP headers using the following JavaScript:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
alert(headers);
```

Comment: That doesn't give you the headers of the page you're on, it gives you the headers of a different request. You request the same page, but that doesn't mean the request is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being the noob that I am, I've quickly learned that it is not practical/most often not possible to use JavaScript within an email.